# Use WP 3.1 Internal Linking 'widget' as a meta_box

Tags: custom-field, linking

There is lots of information out there on how to customize meta boxes added with add_meta_box(), such as enabling WYSIWYG editors on textareas and uploading images.

What I have yet to find is a way to reuse WordPress 3.1 Internal Linking feature. Many of my custom fields contain urls to other pages on the site. The new Internal Linking feature would make it a lot easier for my users to find a page URL rather than having to remember it of cut & paste it.

Is the new Internal Linking feature reusable in conjunction with add_meta_box()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress 3.1 Internal Linking feature was coded as a TinyMCE editor plugin so its not really a widget or a meta box but you can code your own meta box and reuse the functiona needed for that.

The files you need to look at are

- /wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-mce-link.php
- /wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/js/wplink.js
  and maybe a few more but these are the main files you will need to achieve this functionality.

Side note:  I can tell you that up until now when ever i needed to let my user add a url to a post or a page as a custom field i always created a dropdown select  with the names of my posts and there id as value, then when i needed to show that  link i'd call `get_the_permalink(selected_ID);`.
Now i know that this won't work in all cases but its an option and i wanted to post it here for future reference.

Hope this helps,

Ohad.

Comment: @בניית אתרים  Thanks! Yes a dropdown with pages/posts are a possible solution but I find the Search feature very useful. I am looking for a way to leverage the existing functionality rather than have to rebuild it myself. To let other users give their advice, will leave the question unanswered for the day.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work using Wordpress 3.1's official internal linking?

Comment: @Joe No I did not get it to work ... I decided to roll my own rather than try to use the existing one. I create a plugin called I called post-selector that displays the list of content like the Internal Linking feature, but inline, not in a modal window. With JS I just send the Id of the selected post to a hidden field. I still need to ajaxify it and add search functionality.

Comment: @Bundarr let us know if you need any help

Comment: @Bainternet - can you post an example of your select box code?

Comment: @codecowboy: ask it as a new question and i promise to answer it with an example.