# Utilize TinyMCE hyperlink chooser outside of TinyMCE

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, tinymce

Is it possible to use the "Insert/edit link" dialog box outside of TinyMCE?  For example, if I wanted to add that dialog box to a generic button within a plugin settings form, is it possible to include just the portion of the TinyMCE that is required to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was asked before, but sadly the "Insert/edit link" (with interlinking) was developed as a tinymce plugin so using it outside of tinymce is not really possible unless your write the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this previous question? I see that [the link editor](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/js/wplink.dev.js) only references the editor via the `TinyMCEPopup` class. Maybe if we can create a stub editor and add it to the `EditorManager`, we can fake everything this plugin needs...

Comment: @Jan: took a while but i've found it http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8749/use-wp-3-1-internal-linking-widget-as-a-meta-box

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just write a JS file to open a popup, ask for a link and return the appropriate HTML? Why muck around with TinyMCE just to use a single button?

Comment: That would be easier but i think he is looking for the new internal linking with the search features.